# Linkedin+Codeigniter : linkedin status update using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, linkedin-api

could any one guide me on how can I update status on linkedin using codeigniter?

Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: Some tips for future.  1) Show some effort into researching your question in future.  2) Don't just ask to be spoon fed.  3) Write your questions properly.  4) When you get some answers at least come back, review them and then accept one of them!

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this library into CI to make sure a user could log in with his LinkedIn profile. Maybe you can also update the status of a user.

http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/

Implementing it in CI is pretty easy if you know your way around in CI.

Comment: I already tried using this library ... it doesn't work ... the authentication runs fine but the status update doesnt work

Comment: Add a bug report then. They might fix it for you.

Comment: Having banged my head for a long time on the POS code of Sudhir.  Dude your code is horrible, go back and fix it!  Although I am new to CI, I managed to do the same as P.T and implemented the lib into CI.  The simple-linkedinphp class works like a charm.  I can now authorise an app, authenticate, get profile details and even post to linkedin.  I even posted a comment on Sundir's blog that it doesn't work and he deleted the comment!  Stay away, well away if you don't want any headaches!

Comment: P.T, if you can please put your code on github, pastebin or wherever.  There is a real lack of good examples of getting Linkedin working with CI.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I really like it when people write libraries for others to use and the code is commented/well thought out/well structured and is easy to follow.

I tried the other examples, but settled on this one.

http://blog.justni.com/posting-to-linkedin-from-php-and-codeigniter/

Edit:

Having banged my head for a long time on the POS code of Sudhir and the code above.  Yes I can change my opinion, because when I started to work on it, it just doesn't work!.

Although I am new to CI, I managed to do the same as P.T and implemented the lib into CI.

The simple-linkedinphp class works like a charm.

I can now authorise an app, authenticate, get profile details and even post to linkedin.

I even posted a comment on Sundir's blog that it doesn't work and he deleted the comment! Stay away, well away if you don't want any headaches!

Comment: Upon review is similar to what Sudhir has posted.  Someone is stealing someone elses code lol.....

Comment: Oh ! I am very sorry ! Everything works fine like I request and get the tokens and store them in a session as opposed to the database, but then when I try to use them it doesnt work the post doesnt get posted on linked in

Comment: out of interest what version of CI you running?

Comment: Latest ! I downloaded it 2 days before i posted this question .... also I turned the cookie and session encryption on could that effect the code in some way?